# Как создать случайную строку байтов в C#?

Tags: python, c#

Сабж.
Пытаюсь перевести код python в C#
Есть такой кусок кода

```python
import base64
import hashlib
import secrets

random = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(32))
```

`secrets.token_bytes(32)` возвращает случайную строку байтов, содержащую количество байтов nbytes.

А `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()` принимает "байтоподобный объект".

Есть у меня такой C# код

```cs
public static byte[] GetByteArray()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    byte[] b = new byte[32]; 
    rnd.NextBytes(b);
    return b;
}
```

Но это массив байтов. окей.
Делаю `BitConverter.ToString(key)` получаю строку вида `75-A7-A0-85-D3-05-8E-.......` Но она не такая как в документации питона

```python
>>> token_bytes(16)  
b'\xebr\x17D*t\xae\xd4\xe3S\xb6\xe2\xebP1\x8b'
```

Что не так? Как мне получить такую же строку?

**upd**

Да, по коду питона мне дальше нужно

```python
random = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(secrets.token_bytes(32)) 
m = hashlib.sha256() 
m.update(random) 
d = m.digest() 
code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(d).decode().replace("=", "")
```

Но это я уже знаю как дальше. Но мне нужна строка байтов. 
Просто с массивом байтов я уже пробовал делать и у меня не получается. 
**upd2** 
Я незнаю почему мне нужна строка вида `\xebr\xe2\xebP1\x8b` это мне нужно для OAuth 2.0, есть пример на python я пытаюсь его полностью повторить.  
Потому что когда на C# я генерирую массив байтов потом его в Base64 потом его в mySHA256 потом его в Base64 как в инструкции `<URL safe Base64(SHA256(URL safe Base64(random 32 byte string)))>` у меня ничего не работает

Comment: Вам не надо BitConverter.ToString(key), у Вас и так уже байты на выходе, b'\xebr\x17D*t\xae...' - тоже байты, просто их так отображает питон. \xeb - 0xEB - нет латинского символа с таким кодом, поэтому он показывает его в HEX формате

Comment: Зачем вам эти байты? Криптография или другие задачи? Как будете использовать и зачем именно нужна строка `\x`?

Comment: Добавил ответ в вопрос

Comment: Не используйте HTML код сниппет для вставки не фронтенда, треяется подсветка кода и много лишнего показывает. Используйте форматирование кода как я сделал когда отредактировал вопрос. Тег `python` можно убрать, так как очевидно вам не нужен ответ на питоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для криптографии можно использовать криптостойкий PRNG `RandomNumberGenerator`.

Получится как-то так, если я верно понял код

```cs
private static string ToUrlSafeBase64(byte[] bytes, bool trimPadding = false)
{
    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
        .Replace('+', '-')
        .Replace('/', '_');
    return trimPadding ? result.TrimEnd('=') : result;
}
```

```cs
string base64key = ToUrlSafeBase64(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32));
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64key);
byte[] hash = SHA256.HashData(bytes);
string base64 = ToUrlSafeBase64(hash, true);
Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

Пример вывода в консоль

```
-XQ8VkSPUMFDW8m9d_xnzPYvFhrordTV-TUQConvVbE
```

Comment: А как мне сделать `<URL safe Base64(SHA256(URL safe Base64(random 32 byte string)))>` ?

Comment: @User12351259599491 так я вам ее и дал, то есть воспроизвел питоновский код 1 в 1

Comment: Спасибо значит проблема была не в этой части кода.

Comment: @User12351259599491 `ToUrlSafeBase64(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32))` - можно еще тримминг паддинга сделать здесь - `ToUrlSafeBase64(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32), true)`, но в питоновском коде его нет.

Comment: Я просто потом отправляю не хешированную строку в base64 и мне ответ от сайта что это не так строка которая была в первый раз. Я это описал в вопросе который на конкурсе сейчас висит. Хотя это та строка 100% потому что я проверял что бы оно все назад могло переконверить.

Comment: @User12351259599491 а зачем дубликат вопроса создаете?

Comment: Это не дубликат, там я спрашиваю как пройти авторизацию, а тут как создать строку байтов.

Comment: @User12351259599491 во тому вопросу, вам нужно сохранить те сгенерированные 32 байта. В коде выше это Base64Key. Еще в документации, которую вы показали, я нигде не вижу что убирается паддинг. То есть попробуйте без `trimPadding` сделать либо в обоих случаях включить, я хз